# Read multiple tables in one text file to pandas dataframe/dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files, etl

```
---------------------------------------------------
|books field              |names       |          |
|---------------------  --------------------------|
|                         |comedy      |          |
|                         |comics      |          |
|                         |fashion     |          |
---------------------------------------------------
Company.                                                                   Books                                                         Time 01:00:00     Date  01/01/2001
company1   books 01                                                                                                                            text/text1  Page           1
company texts 01-01 2001 to date 01-01 2001
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|code b/c code   Crcy  b/c code Text                                 book    Before price    before,prev.price       after rept.price      Credit money.     total balance|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|0101 1234567    USD   comic book                                            7.53            6.23                    0.00                    0.00                   10.20 |
|0101 1234567    USD   fashion book new - number 8555                        2.12            3.2                     0.00                    0.00                   2.06  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company.                                                                   Books                                                         Time 01:00:00     Date  01/01/2001
company1   books 01                                                                                                                            text/text1  Page           2
company texts 01-01 2001 to date 01-01 2001
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|code b/c code   Crcy  b/c code Text                                 book    Before price    before,prev.price       after rept.price      Credit money.     total balance|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|0102 8234567    USD   comic book                                            2.53            1.23                    0.00                    0.00                   9.20 |
|0102 8234567    USD   fashion book new - number 8555                        1.12            1.2                     0.00                    0.00                   1.06  |
```

I am expecting 2 types of results

1. All tables in a single dataframe

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|code b/c code   Crcy  b/c code Text                                 book    Before price    before,prev.price       after rept.price      Credit money.     total balance|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|0101 1234567    USD   comic book                                            7.53            6.23                    0.00                    0.00                   10.20 |
|0101 1234567    USD   fashion book new - number 8555                        2.12            3.2                     0.00                    0.00                   2.06  |
|0102 8234567    USD   comic book                                            2.53            1.23                    0.00                    0.00                   9.20 |
|0102 8234567    USD   fashion book new - number 8555                        1.12            1.2                     0.00                    0.00                   1.06  |
```

2. All tables in multiple dataframes

```
CompanyA
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|code b/c code   Crcy  b/c code Text                                 book    Before price    before,prev.price       after rept.price      Credit money.     total balance|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|0101 1234567    USD   comic book                                            7.53            6.23                    0.00                    0.00                   10.20 |
|0101 1234567    USD   fashion book new - number 8555                        2.12            3.2                     0.00                    0.00                   2.06  |

CompanyB
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|code b/c code   Crcy  b/c code Text                                 book    Before price    before,prev.price       after rept.price      Credit money.     total balance|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|0102 8234567    USD   comic book                                            2.53            1.23                    0.00                    0.00                   9.20 |
|0102 8234567    USD   fashion book new - number 8555                        1.12            1.2                     0.00                    0.00                   1.06  |

Please help me with this problem.
```

Comment: You might want to preprocess this file and make it more computer-read-compatible. Pelase [edit] your post, you put all into one `code block`. Please share what you did to achieve your goal as [mre] and explain what went wrong.

Comment: Add each table to excel sheets and convert the excel sheets to dataframe